# Inserting string to SQLite using Android

Tags: android, sqlite

How do we insert  strings that have commas (,) in them into SQLite database using Android ?

If there are no commas within the values to be inserted, then insertion happens fine. Say for example see the Android code:-

```
db.execSQL("insert into Student ( id, name, mark ) values (1, 'Geevarghese', 100)");
```

Inserting into the db works well.

If I modify my question to add the address to the database, like the following,

```
db.execSQL("insert into Student ( id, name, mark, address ) values (1, 'Geevarghese', 100, 'No.20, Cochin, Kerala')");
```

This query doesn't insert data into the database

How to properly insert data that includes comma into SQLite db from Android ?

Comment: use scape sequence \ for each special character that you want as string to be inserted in db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **ContentValues** as follow:

```
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

initialValues.put("id", 1);
initialValues.put("name", "Geevarghese");
initialValues.put("mark", 100);
initialValues.put("address", "No.20, Cochin, Kerala");

db.insert("Student", null, initialValues);
```

Ref:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html

Hope It helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String data = "No.20, Cochin, Kerala";
data = data.replaceAll("," , "\,");


db.execSQL("insert into Student ( id, name, mark, address ) values (1, 'Geevarghese', 100, '"+data+"')");
```